# how to embedded a linux command example ln -l path1 path2 in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, symlink

im trying to create a symlink to a path /appdata/config/hello.txt to /appdata/debug/

```
std::string srcpath = "/appdata/config/hello.txt";
std::string debug = "/appdata/debug/";
```

In cpp code I have given `ln -s srcpath debug`

I even tried `if(symlink(destPath.c_str(), DEBUG_PATH.c_str()) == 0)`

But no luck.

Comment: what error (via errno) did you get when `symlink()` failed?

Comment: Do you use c++17? May give a try on this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink

Comment: What order of parameters do you use? The `ln -s` command has them reversed. The `symlink` call is using `destPath` instead of `srcpath` above which also looks suspicious.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin no we arent using c++17.

Comment: @JanKratochvil please consider `ln -s  destPath DEBUG_PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the *target* link name as well, e.g. like this:

```
std::string fileName = "hello.txt";
std::string srcpath = "/appdata/config/" + fileName;
std::string tgtpath= "/appdata/debug/" + fileName;

if (symlink(srcpath.c_str(), tgtpath.c_str()) != 0) {
  std::cerr<< strerror(errno) << std::endl; // #include <errno.h> and <cstring> for this
}
```

The way you've written it the program will output an "File exists" error message, because you're defining an existing directory as link target.